# MySQL suddenly fails to start

Tags: server, mysql

MySQL suddenly shuts down and fails at start. Problem in InnoDB that can't access directory.

I tried to set excuse me access to MySQL but still can't.

The log is:

```
2022-12-16T05:16:36.560556Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-012894] [InnoDB] Unable to open './#innodb_redo/#ib_redo70' (error: 1000).
2022-12-16T05:16:37.498231Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-012592] [InnoDB] Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
2022-12-16T05:16:37.498295Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-012595] [InnoDB] The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to the directory.
2022-12-16T05:16:37.498319Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013901] [InnoDB] Failed to resize unused redo log file ./#innodb_redo/#ib_redo71_tmp to 3 MB (Failed to retrieve status of the file).
2022-12-16T05:16:37.498346Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-012891] [InnoDB] Failed to create redo log file ./#innodb_redo/#ib_redo71 (error: 11) for start LSN 798189056
2022-12-16T05:16:37.498370Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013864] [InnoDB] [FATAL] Error 11 encountered when writing to the redo log file: ./#innodb_redo/#ib_redo70.
2022-12-16T05:16:37.498392Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013183] [InnoDB] Assertion failure: log0write.cc:2117:ib::fatal triggered thread 140042740778752
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
2022-12-16T05:16:37Z UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
BuildID[sha1]=42fffe844f4ae6ac576008e5df6b737ffd4d4eef
Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x100000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace(unsigned char const*, unsigned long)+0x41) [0x5576d4f3bf11]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(print_fatal_signal(int)+0x39b) [0x5576d3dcd97b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_server_abort()+0x76) [0x5576d3dcdac6]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_abort()+0xe) [0x5576d4f35f3e]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(ut_dbg_assertion_failed(char const*, char const*, unsigned long)+0x349) [0x5576d51c8759]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(ib::fatal::~fatal()+0xd5) [0x5576d51caf65]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x2411255) [0x5576d5087255]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x241355b) [0x5576d508955b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(log_writer(log_t*)+0xc68) [0x5576d508be98]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(std::thread::_State_impl<std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<Detached_thread, void (*)(log_t*), log_t*> > >::_M_run()+0xc8) [0x5576d5050468]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0xd6de4) [0x7f5e696e9de4]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x8609) [0x7f5e69805609]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x43) [0x7f5e693d6163]
```

The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains information that should help to find out what is causing the crash.

Comment: I unfortunately cannot help you but others will need to know at least the version of Ubuntu and MySQL you're using.

Comment: ubuntu 20 and mysql 5.o, before is fine , but after transfer file app to 'www' and create vhost and chown folder suddenly mysql down. please help me

Comment: If MySQL was working previously, then one of three things likely happened: 1. Someone performed a `sudo chown` operation 2. Someone deleted a redo file 3. Someone performed a `sudo chmod` command. More information about your system will be required.

Comment: yes, folder /var/ not user root, maybe this is problem, folder var is changed to root, but mysql not run, what is mysql folder permission? i dont know